# Is There a Way to Remove These ANSI Escape Codes From the Terminal Output?

Tags: python, configuration, interpreter

I am trying to configure python 3.12.0 within CLion, it doesnt look to pose any issues, but when I run a test program, this is the output:

```
C:\Python312\python.exe C:\Users\myname\CLionProjects\untitled\Test.py 
[0m[0KHello, world[0K[?25l
[0K[?25h
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've tried running commands and troubleshooting, but to no eval.

Comment: What is the test program? In general, when seeking help here, if you want someone to be able to explain how to change your output, they need to see the code that produced it.

Comment: `print("Hello, world")`

Comment: If you put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the first line of the script, does that change the output?

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. Is it most likely an issue with how I set up the configuration within CLion?